# Handsontable restrict particular column to numeric keyboard to mobile browsers

Tags: jquery, mobile, handsontable

I am using `Handsontable` to populate my data:

I have an example fiddle as follows:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/santhucool007/r7g9t7en/)

Mobile browsers in android/ios, when I tap on Year column it appears in a keyboard with its default keyboard.

**I want to restrict the keyboard to numeric only for year column**

What I am expecting is something as follows if I say in normal text field:

```
<input id="year" name="input_year" class="form-control form-control-solid placeholder-no-fix" type="number" min="0" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*"  placeholder="Year"/>
```

How can I implement the same in handsontable?

Comment: Generally using `type="number"` will bring up the numeric keypad. Is this working?

Comment: @ ZekeDroid I know it. But how to implement it in handsontable? Read question correctly buddy!